How to create POSITIVE keywords in a google ad campaign?
I have a google ads campaign.  If I go to Google Ads, click on Campaigns on the left, Choose my campaign, then choose the ad group,
Next I choose "Audiences, keywords and content", Then "search keywords"... It shows me my NEGATIVE keyword list.
What if I don't want to use NEGATIVE keywords, but instead, I only want my ads to show if specific words or phrases are typed.  Every other word or phase on the planet would then be "Negative."   Is there a way to do that?   I see no option for POSITIVE keywords.  Or an option to make EVERYTHING negative except... whatever words I want.

Thanks Geoff, but I have a Shopping campaign. My problem is, I'm getting millions of impressions, but very few clicks. It's showing me what keywords people are entering to make my products appear. They are all keywords that aren't quite related to my products. For example, Let's say I was selling cheese and cheese related products. My ads are appearing when people search for any type of food or food product, not just cheese. It gives me the option to set those keywords as Negative. Well, there could be a million food related keywords that I don't want. I'd be entering negative keywords all day. I would think it would make more sense to just have a positive keyword option so my products only show when someone searches for something specific, like a cheese grater. Let's say I only sold 3 products. "Cheese Grater", "Cheese Knife" and "Cutting board." Is there any way to get my products to appear ONLY when those 3 keywords are entered?

Under the page title, it should have two options; Search Keywords and Negative Keywords. Of course that is depending on the campaign type. If it's not a search campaign, it wouldn't have search keywords.
